# How to obtain JSON response in speech-to-text-websockets-python?

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Looking at the https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-websockets-python How can I update the project to to obtain the different timestamps and transcription in JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

the project already produces json output with timestamps. Look for the files "*.json.txt" in the output directory:

```
{
    "result_index": 0, 
    "results": [
        {
            "alternatives": [
                {
                    "timestamps": [
                        [
                            "so", 
                            1.0, 
                            1.27
                        ]
                    ], 
                    "transcript": "so "
                }
            ], 
            "final": false
        }
    ]
}
```